# Android Studio - Activity Life Cycles, On Resume

Tags: android, onresume, activity-lifecycle

How can I know whether an activity has entered onResume due to a button being pressed and hence intent started, or if the user selected to navigate back?

EDIT:

- Basically, Activity A is playing a song
- You can choose a new song to be played in Activity B, which sends an intent back to activity A to start a new song
- But at the moment if "back" is pressed from Activity B, I need the song to continue playing, rather than what it does at the moment which is restart as it runs the intent from previuosly in onResume();

Comment: you can try putting different logs on button onClick before starting an intent and and on onBackpressed

Comment: It might be worth clarifying whether you mean your UI buttons, or soft buttons on the phone (back, home, ...).

Comment: Your question shows misconception. Describe your intentions precisely and what you try to accomplish. It will help you to get reasonable replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user navigates from the `Activity` to another `Activity` you can use `startActivityForResult` and set parameters, such as which button is pressed, in the `setResult` of the new `Activity`.

What you cannot do is always know how the user got to `onResume` since things happen out of your control For example a phone call could background the app, and once it's done, it returns to the foreground.

You can also use `onNewIntent` to help with navigation from another `Activity` that did not start the `Activity` you are trying to monitor, in cases where you have indirect actions (like Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C -> Activity A).

For `PendingIntents` you can also include data about the launching app/`Activity`.

EDIT:

If you are just trying to put data into an `Intent` so that when the `Activity` is launched, then you can use code like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BUTTON_ID", "button_a");
startActivity(intent);
```

However, remember that you will need to use `onNewIntent` if the `Activity` is already running an a new `Intent` is sent to the `Activity` to "start" it. That seems to be the core problem that you are having. However, you also need to "reset" the intent data after consuming it - otherwise if the `Activity` is resumed without a new `Intent` then you will still have the old `Intent` data.

Comment: essentially I want my code as such: if(intent started via button in Activity B) then do A, else - anything else -

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onBackPressed` to see if the user has pressed the Back button. However, the user can still press the Home/Recents button to send the activity to the background.